# com.google.android.gms.vision.ica not found

Tags: kotlin

com.google.android.gms.vision.ica not found.

W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ica not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ica:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ica:0

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vt.shoppet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".ShopPetApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_pet" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/menu_item_chat" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ica" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ica"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
            android:value="true" />

        <service
            android:name=".MessagingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build in Project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", "1.5.30"))
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2")
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks {
    register("clean", Delete::class) {
        delete(rootProject.buildDir)
    }
}
```

built in app

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    ndkVersion = "23.0.75998587"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.vt.shoppet"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 31
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi")
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    lint {
        isCheckDependencies = true
        isCheckGeneratedSources = true
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            isEnable = true
            isUniversalApk = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Kotlin / Java
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2")

    // Android Architecture Components
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")

    // CameraX
    val cameraVersion = "1.0.1"
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:$cameraVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31")

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx")
    implementation ("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1")




    // ML Kit
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-image-labeling:16.0.5")

    // Firebase UI
    val firebaseUiVersion = "8.0.0"
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:$firebaseUiVersion")
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:$firebaseUiVersion")

    // Glide
    val glideVersion = "4.12.0"
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion")
    kapt("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion")

    // Hilt
    val hiltAndroidVersion = "2.38.1"
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltAndroidVersion")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltAndroidVersion")

    // Lifecycle
    val lifecycleVersion = "2.3.1"
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")

    // Material Components
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")

    // Navigation Component
    val navigationVersion = "2.3.5"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

Comment: I added  <meta-data android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ica" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ica"/> in both AndroidManifest.xml and built in app.

Comment: And it still not found.